# Where's the proper home for LabVIEW questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope, on-topic, off-topic

I could imagine asking a LabVIEW question (and believe me, I will be throughout the summer) and I want to post it in a place where it:

1. Won't get downvoted and closed immediately, and
2. get well-informed, thoughtful answers.

I've seen legitimate programming questions closed in EE Stack Exchange, but I also haven't had an amazing experience with StackOverflow in terms of languages that aren't purely programatic. I just want to post where I'll get the most positive results. I'm asking here in meta before finding out the hard way.

Comment: I think it would be a rare LabView question that would be on topic here.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd go right to the Labview forums in the National Instrument support system. http://forums.ni.com/

The folks there might well point you to the tutorials at http://www.ni.com/tutorials/  -- Extend the participants there the courtesy of thoroughly searching the examples before asking questions.

Also, the Learn Labview pages are pretty good.  http://www.ni.com/academic/students/learn/  -- My opinion is that if you follow that sequence from start to finish, you'll have the answer to a good deal of the questions you might come up with.

Comment: All fantastic options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if it regards LabView in terms of "code", so not technical issues with the software itself, it can make a good fit for the site. And I think it's the same for Simulink, since as far as I know they're very popular in the EE world.

Comment: I agree, but just don't think EESE is the forum to get the best help in these areas.  The Matlab proposed SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38040/matlab might be a great place for simulink questions, if it can reach critical mass.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I don't agree: many embedded systems nowadays are programmed with Simulink or LabView, and I think that if we confine ourselves in PCB related questions we'll become obsolete soon.

Comment: I'm talking about where I think a person can get the best help on those topics, not about the future of the site.  I think the topics are on-topic here, and I'd like to see more such questions, but this simply isn't where I'd send a student looking for the best help in those areas right now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Engineering, SuperUser, StackOverflow, and EE all have active [labview] tags. Unclear if one of these has been decided as the "correct" location.